# React-table library- 'useTable' is not exported by node_modules/react-table/index.js

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

```
React version: 16.8.6
React-table version: 7.6.3
```

Hey.
 I am getting the next error only when trying to build my project.
When running it locally, everything works fine and the hook is being imported, but when trying to build it, I am getting:
 `'useTable' is not exported by node_modules/react-table/index.js`. 
Saw some code examples, and I am doing everything exactly the same as them. Tried to remove my `node_modules` and reinstall everything- but it didn't work.

Any help???
Thanks!!

This is the way I am importing the component:
[image]

This is the error I am getting after the build fails:
[image]

Comment: It seems to be working fine https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-frog-f9j3c

Comment: Hey.
Thanks for answering me.
I saw this code example.. as I wrote above, I am doing everything exactly the same..  and the versions are also the same. The code is working perfectly when I run it locally (using "npm start"), but when I am trying to build it- i am getting the above error....